# Fading out a disclosure indicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm building an app where I've got cells that expand, similar to when you create a new event in iOS' built in calendar app. One of the expanding cells have a disclosure indicator set in storyboard, but return nil when logging it. I've tried to set it both in StoryBoard and like this:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

and I'm trying to fade it out like this:

```
self.cell.accessoryView.alpha = 0.0f;
```

but it doesn't work as it's nil.

Can someone help me with this? Why is it nil? I'm using StoryBoard with a UITableViewController that's static and grouped.

Thanks!

Erik

Comment: Setting the accessory **type** is not the same as setting the accessory **view**. Accessory view is `nil` by default and if you set it, it will override the accessory type. AFAIK you can't mess with the default accessory types, all the examples I've seen involve creating a custom accessory view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to provide your own `accessoryView`. `accessoryView` will be nil if you're using an `accessoryType`.

Remember to add a little logic in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to decide whether or not to show your accessoryView as well since the cells get reused.

Comment: how can I provide an accessoryView than differs from my example? Also, I'm using a static and grouped tableView so that's not a problem :)

Comment: You could post another question about that if you can't figure it out after some research. Kind of out of scope for this question.